# Best Solution for Social Backend

Tags: ios, mobile, social-networking, opensocial

Which is the simplest way to deploy a back-end server with social features? The basic features would be

- User Profiles
- Friends
- Activity Streams
- Notifications

Most of the off-the-shelf solutions I find are targeted at social networking "websites" whereas I just need a back-service which provides APIs to be integrated into mobile applications.

I am checking out Open Social but doesn't seem to be as 'out-of-box' as I thought it would be.

What else is out there?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Apache Rave](http://rave.apache.org/) as a more out of the box OpenSocial solution.